# Simplify rearranges equations?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I've been using `Simplify/FullSimplify` to simplify some nasty equations, and by and large it does well but sometimes it rearranges equations in an unhelpful way.

Here's a simple example. Say `x` is a positive number (standing in for some generally much more complicated factors),

```
$Assumptions=x>0
```

I have an equation like

```
eq = x^2 (a + b - 2 c^2 b) == 0
eq // Simplify
```

> ```
> a + b == 2 b c^2
> ```

But I don't want it to move terms from the `LHS` to the `RHS`, splitting up terms proportional to `b`. I want them grouped together.

I can use `Collect` to keep these terms together, but then I have no way of dividing out the `x^2`. I could use `Collect` then divide out the `x^2` manually, but the terms I'm using `x^2` to stand in for are quite unwieldy, and it would be quite laborious to do this case-by-case, especially when `Simplif`y does it right away.

**My question**: Is there any simple way to take `eq` and output

> ```
> a + b - 2c^2 b == 0 
> (* or *)
> a + (1-2c^2)b ==0
> ```

without explicitly specifying that I want to divide out `x^2` (since `Simplify` divides this out automatically)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `Simplify` does is not very well defined.  It tries to put expressions in a simpler form, but what is *usefully* simpler is both subjective and depends on the context.   Simplify aims for "smaller" expressions, for some definition of smaller.

Because of the nature of this function the user doesn't have a lot of control over what it does (though it does have a few options).

For this reason I recommend you post-process the result.  Your requirement seems to be simple and well-defined: have 0 on one side of the equation. So use this transformation rule:

```
Simplify[eq] /. lhs_ == rhs_ :> Simplify[lhs - rhs] == 0
```

Since you'll have zero on one side, you might only want to get the other side, and use

```
Subtract @@ Simplify[eq]
```

A fancier way would be

```
Simplify[ Subtract @@ Simplify[eq], 
   TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, Last@FactorTermsList[#]& }
]
```

This allows `Simplify` to drop any numerical factor from the resulting expression (e.g. a minus sign that might have been introduced by `Subtract`).

Comment: Thanks for these two solutions! To clarify for other users, I've found with the first example that ... should be Simplify[eq], is that right?

Comment: @Adam Yes.  I actually changed the `...` to `Simplify[eq]` a while ago.  If you reload this page, it should show up.